# Function parameter of contructor was null . #Flutter

Tags: function, flutter, parameters

I have a class to change UI between SignInPage and SignUpPage.

```
class Authenticate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticateState createState() => _AuthenticateState();
}

class _AuthenticateState extends State<Authenticate> {
  bool showSignIn = true;
  toggleView() {
    setState(() {
      showSignIn = !showSignIn;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (showSignIn) {
      return SignIn(
        toggleView(),
      );
    } else
      return SignUp(
        toggle: toggleView(),
      );
    ;
  }
}
```

and this is my Contructor in SignInPage

```
 Function toogle;
  @override
  SignIn(Function fun) {
    this.toogle = fun;
  }
```

the toogle always is null and i don't know why :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the function, you should pass it by reference. Now, you are executing the function and passing its result.

Change this:

```
return SignIn(
  toggleView(),
);
```

to this:

```
return SignIn(
  toggleView,
);
```

Also, not sure if `@override` is needed for the constructor, probably you can remove it.